# Run method in active project in Rider plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, rider

I am currently building a plugin for Rider and want to initiate a debugger with the selected project and call a specific method.

Within C# console app, I can use reflection to get the type and method. But then how would I attach this to the Rider debugger?

Comment: Feel free to watch for issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-477355. The only reason it isn't possible for .NET Core applications is this issue not yet being implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is now impossible.